# Using vue.js without NPM or CLI

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to use Vue.js within one page of a large legacy application. The idea is to replace the old JS+jQuery hodge-podge within a single page -- but leave the rest of the app (many other pages) untouched. So, not interested in using NPM, Node, Vue CLI, Webpack, Babel, etc., just yet.

This is a proof-of-concept before we invest in refactoring the entire frontend of the application.

The approach we followed was to include vue.js via  as explained here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Direct-lt-script-gt-Include in that one page, and the use Vue only within that one page.  This is the general page layout:

```
<html>
  <head>
     ...
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
     ...
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div id="el">
      ... vue template ...
    </div>
  
    <script>
      ...
      var vm = new Vue({
        el : '#el',
        data : {
          config : <% config.json %>   // this is server-rendered, using server templating
          ...
        },
        ...
      });
      ...
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The page **does** work. However, I get the following error/warning within the Vue console:

```
Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.
```

Although I'd rather not, I can certainly move the page-specific JS to its own separate file (and that does eliminate the warning/error). However, I wouldn't be able to set `vm.config` with server-provided data along with the loaded page by using server-side template, e.g. `config : <% config.json %>`. I know I could GET it using JS separately, after pageload, via an AJAX call directly from the server, but for practical reasons I'd like to avoid doing that here.

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to get this to work nicely. **I'm also open to other suggestions with regard to this general pattern, that don't involve retooling the front-end just yet.**

And perhaps the answer is to ignore the warning, or somehow disable it, given the page does work as intended...

Thank you!

Comment: Since it's just a proof of concept and your page still works, I would just ignore the warning. If you want to mute that warning, set the `script` type to `application/javascript` (workaround). You could also mute all warnings using the production build of Vue: `<script src=".../dist/vue.min.js">`.

Comment: @tony19, thanks for the reply. setting `script` type to `application/javascript` puts the browser into some sort of endless loop. I'm not sure why. `script` by itself or with the obsolete type `text/javascript` works (but yields the warning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grrr, after several days after enduring this error, I discovered this:

```
<fieldset id="el">
  ...
  <div id="el">
  ...
  </div>
  ...
</fieldset>
```

So the issue was repeating `#el` within same page.

My mistake.

Just wish the error message emitted by Vue had been a bit more useful!

**Bottom line: The pattern described in the origional question works just fine without NPM/CLI.**

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution here is to write it to the global window object. IIRC SSR frameworks like Angular universal/Nuxt/Next/... all use this approach.

```
window.__STATE__ = <% config.json %>
```

In your `JS` file you can then refer to the `window.__STATE__` object.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
   el: '#el',
   data: {
     config: window.__STATE__
   }
})
```

Ofcourse the order is important here:

```
<body>
  <script>
    window.__STATE__ = <% config.json %>
  </script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this technique. Will definitely keep it in mind!  I tried it in this case, but I continue getting the warning. Basically any `<script>` tag that contains code appears to trigger the warning, even though said `<script>` tag is outside of `vm.$el`.  I wonder if this is a bug?

Comment: @yahermann fyi: `<style>` and `<script>` tags trigger the warning

Comment: @tony19, yep, and it feels like a bug, because the `style` & `script` tags only occur **outside** of the Vue root element and components (but within `<body>...</body>`.  I'm living with the errors/warnings for now, but do wish I could mute them!

Comment: I think that bug is unlikely, since Vue only evaluates tags inside the specified element. But feel free to file a GitHub issue with a reproducible example. To mute the warnings, have you tried the production build as I suggested?

Comment: @tony19, you were right. There was another bug. See my answer below.